# Uialtertview -> Insert String -> Segue How?

Tags: ios, swift, segue, uialertview

I am trying to do this sequence

1. Tap a button
2. Display an UiAltertView with textfield
3. Press OK
4. Copy the text inserted through the keyboard in another view

With my actual code there is no segue,I don't understand why
This is what i gat from the output when the uialertview appears:

```
Game1[615:11540] <UIView: 0x798c1d20; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x798ca5f0>>'s window is not equal to <UIAlertController: 0x78e9b6b0>'s view's window!
```

And after i tap the ok button the view doesn't change

Here is the code for the button:

```
   @IBAction func saveScorePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let namePrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Name", message: "You have selected to enter your name", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        namePrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))

    namePrompt.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.placeholder = "Name"
                })

    presentViewController(namePrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
    name = //how do i copy from uialtertview textfield?
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("writelb", sender: nil)

}
```

Here is the segue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if (segue.identifier=="writelb")
    {
        let destinationVC:ViewController4 = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController4
        destinationVC.score = score
        destinationVC.errors = errors
        destinationVC.combo = combo
        destinationVC.comboH = comboH


    }
```

I think that the segue code is right,because i used in other parts of the application without any problem
I don't know how to make the sequence work and how to copy the data from Uialertviewtextfield to a String variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get the name in the line after the call to `presentViewController` because that call does not block.  It presents the view controller and then continues.  You should put the code for the segue into the handler of the "OK" button.  Since the sender of the segue can be any object, you can grab the textField from the alert and make it the sender.  Then in `prepareForSegue` get the text and send it to the destination view controller.

```
@IBAction func goPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let namePrompt = UIAlertController(title: "Enter Name", message: "You have selected to enter your name", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    namePrompt.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction!) in
        if let textFields = namePrompt.textFields as? [UITextField] {
            // Grab the first (only) text field and perform the segue designating
            // the textField as the sender.
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("writelb", sender: textFields[0])
        }
    }))

    namePrompt.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.placeholder = "Name"
    })

    presentViewController(namePrompt, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "writelb" {
        let dvc = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController4
        // Get name from textField and pass it to the destination view controller.
        dvc.name = (sender as UITextField).text
    }
}
```